# Default host compiler used by nvcc for linux

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cuda, nvcc

I am using CUDA 4.0 on Ubuntu 10.10 with GTX 570 (compute capcability 2.0),  with the GCC compiler suite. As I understand it, during compilation the CUDA compiler driver nvcc splits the `.cu` files into host code and device code and calls the host compiler to compile the host code and compiles the device code separately. Finally it merges the generated host object code and the device PTX code into a single executable.

For Linux systems what is the default compiler that is invoked for compiling the host code?  Is it 
the C compiler (`gcc`) or the C++ compiler (`g++`) of the GCC suite?

Comment: perhaps it can be overridden by a `CC` environment variable (like `make` usually does)?

Comment: And you can `strace` programs (even proprietary ones like `nvcc`) to understand the syscalls (and external programs) they are using.

Comment: With the verbose flag (-v) the nvcc will dump all of the executed commands during the compilation. So it will show you whether gcc or g++ is invoked.

Answer (score 16):

You want the `-ccbin` option for `nvcc`, e.g. to use `icpc` (the Intel C++ compiler), use `nvcc -ccbin=icpc` (assuming the `icpc` is available in your `$PATH`).

Note that you should always pass a C++ compiler (`g++`, `icpc`, etc.), since `nvcc` treats the code as C++, even when it's C code.

Comment: Useful answer. This seems to explain the `cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]` messages after compilation of some CUDA sources.

Comment: Useful answer. Is there an existing documentation that mentions this, that it `treats the code as C++` ?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK it uses `g++` (to be more precise it uses `gcc` with language set to c++) and of course `g++` for final linking. Run `nvcc` with `--verbose` option to see more detail if you want.