# gcc linking differently of g++

Tags: gcc, g++, dynamic-linking

I converted a C++ code to C and now I'm trying to change the Makefile as well. I had this:

```
g++ -fPIC -o bin/linux/release/gpu_md5 cuda_md5.c cuda_md5_cpu.c obj/release/cuda_md5_gpu.cu.o 
-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L../../lib64 
-L../../common/lib64/linux -L/opt/cuda/NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK/lib64 -lcudart     
-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L../../lib64 
-L../../common/lib64/linux -L/opt/cuda/NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK/lib64
```

As far as I know I could just change g++ to gcc and it should work well, but it is not. Looks like gcc can't find the functions from cuda_md5_cpu.c that I'm calling in cuda_md5.c (PS: I'm not including cuda_md5_cpu.c in cuda_md5.c):

```
/tmp/ccKdDJiq.o: In function `cuda_compute_md5s':
cuda_md5.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `init_constants'
cuda_md5.c:(.text+0x2e2): undefined reference to `execute_kernel'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong? I just changed from g++ to gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there's a very good chance that `obj/release/cuda_md5_gpu.cu.o` (which you don't seem to be recompiling) has been compiled with a C++ compiler and therefore has symbol names which have been modified by name mangling.

Name mangling is a technique used by C++ compilers to allow different functions to have the same name but with different parameter types (overloading), and C compilers have no need to do this since there is no overloading allowed.

In other words, you may find that `init_constants(int,float);` may simply be morphed by a C compiler into `_init_constants` but, if you use a C++ compiler, you'll get something like `_init_constants_$$_IntFloat` so as to distinguish it from `init_constants(int,double)` or `init_constants(void)`.

So a linker that tries to link together a C-compiled `cuda_md5.c` with a C++-compiled `obj/release/cuda_md5_gpu.cu.o` will not be able to match the function names together.

That's often why you see `extern "C" { ... }` in C++ code, it uses the C rules to export function names (and other things) to the linker to allow linking of C and C++ code together.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not using g++ anymore, here is the makefile http://pastebin.com/Abnh7Vm2

Comment: @FredericoSchardong, I'm sure you're not. But the problem is that CUFILES are not compiled with the makefile, they're added to the `OBJS` list, meaning that they're _already_ compiled. If they were compiled with a C++ compiler (without `extern C`), you'll have this problem.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong, you need to tell _us_ that. Can you see it compiling in the Makefile output? It will only do so (based on line 344) if the dependencies are newer than the object file. If not, the object file will be left as is. You should also be able to tell by using `nm` or similar tool to look at the symbols in that object file.

Comment: I'm removing all *.o before compiling, also, I see cuda_md5_gpu.cu.o getting created. Sorry for my ignorance, what is nm?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong, `nm` is a UNIX tool that shows the symbols within an object file.

Comment: here is the output of nm on the executable compiled with g++ http://pastebin.com/qbFHzgik is that what you meant?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong, if that's your actual object file, it's definitely a C++ one. For a start, the header line says `#nm of the executable compiled with g++` and the execute_kernel function is `_Z14execute_kerneliiiiiPjS_` (all those `i` characters mean `int` arguments) so mangling is definitely happening.

Comment: as I said it is the result of when I compile the source with g++, I can not give you a nm result compiling with gcc because I can't compile it. :)

Comment: and I wrote that #nm of the executable compiled with g++

Comment: this might help http://pastebin.com/PV0rJqLF is the nm result of obj/release/cuda_md5_gpu.cu.o

Comment: @FredericoSchardong, that's still C++ as evidenced by the `iiiiii` stuff. Hence that library is being compiled by a C++ compiler, hence my answer is correct. You need to find out how to get that compiled with a C compiler. I can't help you with that since I don't use CUDA, so you'll need to search through whatever docs you have to find out how it's done.

Comment: looks like nvcc (cuda compiler) uses gcc with language set to c++. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317510/default-host-compiler-used-by-nvcc-for-linux

Comment: problem solved, I added extern "C" to the functions that the linker was complaining then it worked! Thank you for your help!